# Prove that C is connected whenever there exists a connected subset.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $C \subseteq X$ be a subset so that whenever $x,y \in C$ there exists a connected subset $A \subseteq C$ so that $x,y \in A$. Prove that $C$ is connected.

Suppose to the contrary, that $C$ is disconnected.
Then there exist non-empty subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $C=A \cup B$. How do we go forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $A$ and $B$ should be open.

Suppose that we can take $x\in A,\ y\in B.$ Then, by assumption, there exists a connected subset $C'$ of $C$ so that $x,y\in C'.$ Note that $C'\subset A\cup B.$ Can you finish from here?

EDIT: Details for remainder of the proof are in comments below. I'll add them here, as a spoiler:

> Consider $A'=A\cap C'$ and $B'=B\cap C'$. These are disjoint, relatively open, non-empty ($x\in A', y\in B'$), and have union $C'$. This forms a disconnection of the connected set $C',$ a contradiction. So, we cannot have arbitrary elements $x,y$ with $x\in A$ and $y\in B.$ Hence, every element of $C$ is contained in either $A$ or $B$, contradicting that both are non-empty.

Comment: Are we assuming that $C=A\cup B$ and then trying to show that C is connected by showing A and B are not separated?

Comment: Yup. I'm proceeding as you did, and we're going to have to conclude that either $A$ or $B$ is empty, which will follow from the conectedness of $C'.$

Comment: How would it follow from the connectedness of $C'$. Would we then define $C'=A' \cup B'$ and then assume either A' and B' are empty or A' and B' are not seperated?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. If you intersect $C'$ with $A$ and $B$, you have a disconnection of $C'$, and since this set is connected, you know either $A\cap C'$ or $B\cap C'$ is empty. Let's say that it is the latter. This cannot happen, since $y\in B$ and $y\in C'!$

Comment: sorry im confused, how does this prove C is connected, we haven't shown A or B is empty

Comment: No problem; this means that every element of $C$ must be contained in $A$, so $B=\emptyset.$

Comment: @s_healy I've clarified in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A,y\in B$. Then if $x,y\in C'\subset C$, I claim $C'$ is disconnected.   Define $A'=A\cap C',B'=B\cap C'$.  Then $A'$ and $B'$ disconnect $C'$.  That is, $A'\neq\emptyset, B'\neq\emptyset, A'\cup B'=C'$ and $A'\cap B'=\emptyset$.